# NancyFx - How to Dispose instances registered as singleton in application container?

Tags: c#, .net, nancy

My specific context is a self hosted Nancy application, where I'm using RavenDb embedded document database.

My bootstrap looks like this:

```cs
public class MyBootstrapper : DefaultNancyBootstrapper
{
    protected override void ConfigureApplicationContainer(TinyIoCContainer container)
    {
        base.ConfigureApplicationContainer(container);

        container.Register<IDocumentStore>(CreateDefaultStore());
        container.Register<IDoSomething, MyOtherType>().AsSingleton(); // implements IDisposable
    }

    private static IDocumentStore CreateDefaultStore(){...}
}
```

The problem is that I was expecting the Dispose method of the IDocumentStore and of my custom  disposable type to be called when the NanyHost is stopped.

The NancyHost implements IDisposable, the TinyIoCContainer implements IDisposable, if I register a type that implements IDisposable into the request container it will be disposed. I was almost sure that when the Host is disposed the container will be disposed and that all registered instances will be disposed.

I know I can store a reference to the document store outside the bootstrapper and dispose it after the host is stopped and I can also think of some other tricks like having the bootstraper implement IDisposable and dispose it **manually** after the host stops, but I was hopping that there is a more automatic way of handling the disposal of all the instances registered.

Am I missing some clever way to call Dispose() on the singleton instances that are registered in the application container?

My guess is that since the host & application container are expected to live until the application ends, disposing the container was not a priority, but still, this seems like a bad practice if that is the case.

**UPDATE**:
After posting, i'I've found [this thread on the nancy group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/nancy-web-framework/dispose/nancy-web-framework/s87mfvdEmhw/PWx8fXNYRCIJ) which has some information related to this, but is a bit old.

Comment: Singleton are made to live untill application stops so why you want to dispose something that isn't disposable?

Comment: I guess there are valid reasons for singletons to do cleanup at application shutdown. ( cleanup, release unmanaged resources etc )

Comment: @IulianMargarintescu - you would never put unmanaged resources in a static instance to begin with... Document Store is not an unmanaged resource. If its not disposed of properly it doesn't matter.

Comment: @Phill since the doc store implements IDisposable, I rather not assume that it does not matter if it is disposed or not. Looking at [the source](https://github.com/ravendb/ravendb/blob/master/Raven.Client.Embedded/EmbeddableDocumentStore.cs#L148) it appears to actually do a lot, and I would feel better having it done in a deterministic way by calling Dispose() rather than relying on the GC and the app ending.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although this shouldn't be required for app shutdown, in self hosted and OWIN scenarios you may want to "restart" the server component, without tearing down the AppDomain - in these scenarios being more deterministic about finalisation is obviously beneficial.

To that end, I've altered the bootstrapper to be disposable, made our bootstrapper base class dispose the app container (if it implements IDisposable), and wired up the hosting to dispose it all when the host is disposed:

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/pull/1268

Comment: Thanks. Restarting the host in slef hosted scenario might simplify one of the usecases I have.

Answer (score 2):

Reading the source you provide, RavenDb does not implement the IDIsposable pattern fully. According to the best practices, [a class which implements IDisposable should have finalizer, which cleans unmanaged resources](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms244737.aspx). In that case, the GC will do whatever is required.

In the RavenDb code you provided, the Dispose method does not deal with any unmanaged resources, so there shouldn't be any leaks, if it's not called. This of course assumes that the managed resources, referenced by `EmbeddableDocumentStore` have "proper" IDisposable pattern implemented, if they hold unmanaged resources (I didn't check that).

If you still have concerns, you can:

1. File a bug request against RavenDb, so they fix that
2. Use a wrapper around DocumentStore, which implements IDisposable pattern correctly.

In any case, I do not see "relaying on .Net framework to do it's job" as a bad thing, unless a proven bug/need exists. As the assumption is, that the application container exists throughout the life-cycle of the application, when the application is terminated, GC will take care of the proper disposing.

Comment: whenever i see something implementing IDisposable, especially for 3rd party code, i feel that I must dispose it. This would be correct when the instance lives until app end, but would also remain correct if the assumption changes in the future and the instance has a shorter lifespan. So while at the moment it is not an issue since the GC will do its job, if it costs me nothing, I rather be future proof and have the instance disposed. Also with Steven Robbins's change I don't have to change anything in my code, and the behaviour would be what I expected in the first place.

Comment: I agree that when you see IDisposable, you need to use it. It was meant for that - to dispose resource as soon as you no longer need it. In application scope - it is ... after the application ends :). Anyway, the change Steven Robbins is doing is good for the specific situation.